# Azure release management with visual studio online

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm looking for some advices concerning release management in azure
I've found a lot of ressources, but I still have some questions

I have an asp.net 4 solution (to make it simple : one asp.net project, one database project, one test project)
I'm using GIT in visual studio online

At this moment I have one app service and one sql server database in azure.
I have a build that download nuget packages, build, execute a dacpac for the database, executes the tests from the project (I have integration tests that uses the database) and finaly deploys the app on an azure app services

What I want to do seems a "normal stuff" :

I want to cerate the build, then deploy it on a "dev" environnement in azure, then in a "qa" environnement, then in a "stagging" and in "prod"

In my web project, I created different web.config transformations (one for each environnement)

I've seen the releases in visual studio online and I get that its for the deployment part in different environnements

What I have questions with :

In Azure  :

- Do I create 1 app service by environnement ? or do I create  a single app service and use slots ?
- Do I create 1 sql server for each environnement or is it best to use a single sql server and to have one database for each environnement ?

In visual studio online :

- How do I do the tasks ?
- In the build part, what configuration do I use ? Which environnement do I select ?
- In the build, how do I manage the database project ? I thing the deployment part should be in the release part, but I don't see how to configure the connexionstring ?
- For the tests -> Do I execute them in the release part? How do I change the connexionstrings and appsettings? there is no transformations for the app.config
- I've seen that there is test-plans as well, but I don't really get it

Can somebody help me to see a little bit better in all of that ?

Comment: thats a lot of questions for 1 question...

Comment: yes, I know that's a lot of questions, but I feel that if I ask them in different posts it will not be precise

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer all of these, but I can answer a few.

I would create separate Web App instances for your separate environments. With slots, your slots exist on the same Web App and share computing resources. If something goes horribly wrong (your staging code pegs CPU to 100% or eats all of your RAM), this will cause problems for your production slot. I see slots as part of A/B testing or to aid in deployment.

You will likely need to create a separate database per environment as well. This is almost always required if you will be upgrading your database schema at any point in the future and introduce breaking changes to your database schema. For example, what happens if your production code requires a specific field in a database table, but your next version of the database removes that field?

You mentioned you're using web.config transforms, but I want to throw out another option that we've found to be easier and have fewer moving parts and sources for error. If you're just changing connection strings and AppSettings, consider using the Web App's application settings per environment. These override whatever is in your web.config. Doing so means you can forget about web.config transforms and not have one more thing that could possibly go wrong in a deployment.

Since you're using a Database project, to deploy your database, check out the VSTS Azure SQL Database Deployment task. It'll use your database project to create a DACPAC, and then deploy that to your target server.

Comment: Thank you for your input Rob ! 
I will remove the web.config transform and configure on the web app directly :)

Now I'm searching for a way to specify a connection string for a "visual studio test" task. When I run my tests in visual studio it uses the app.config, but in visual studio online I need another connectionstring. Can you help me with that ?